# What dose mean by Resource id #35?and #8?

Tags: php, mysql, resources

i am connecting to different Servers DB it shows Resource id #35 and Resource id #8, whats does mean by the Resource id #35?
code is below.

```
$linkLive   = mysql_connect($lhost,$luname,$lpass) or die(mysql_error());
$linkBackup = mysql_connect($bhost,$buname,$bpass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($ldb,$linkLive);
mysql_select_db($bdb,$linkBackup);
$conFrom = ($server == 1)?$linkLive:$linkBackup; 
$conTo   = ($server == 1)?$linkBackup:$linkLive; 
echo $conFrom;
echo "<br>";
echo $conTo;
exit;
```

Result:
Resource id #8
Resource id #35

Answer (score 0):

it is because $conFrom and $conTo is still a mysql resource.
You still need to fetch the values from the resource like below:

```
$conFrom = $row["YOUR COLUMN"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so? Your code just says Select this connection if so and select that connection if so, and then you are echoing a connection, which surely is only a resource. Nothing more to it. Now you can take that connection and run queries on it and get data from database or add etc.

**mysql_connect [deprecated]**

> Returns a MySQL link identifier on success or FALSE on failure.

If you still want to see the details of the link identifier itself, try a `var_dump`.

```
var_dump($conFrom);
```

Comment: my question is simple: what is the means by Resource id #8 and Resource id #35. are both connections are true and successfull? if success full then